# Spring integration using websockets on tomcat 7

Tags: tomcat7, spring-integration, spring-websocket

Is it possible to use spring-integration sockjs websocket on tomcat 7?

Answer (score 0):

The SockJS WebSocket emulation doesn't relate to the Tomcat version.

The Spring Integration WebSocket support is fully based on the Spring WebSocket foundation. The SockJS options and functionality in the Spring Integration are fully the same like they are in the Spring WebSocket support.

If your Tomcat instance supports WebSocket, you can go a head with SockJS fallback service.

See more info in the articale: http://www.concretepage.com/spring-4/spring-4-websocket-sockjs-stomp-tomcat-example